# Python 3.6 matplot lib error: AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'projections'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Getting this error when trying to run this line:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'projections'
```

I have:

- Tried in a new env
- tried to install in new env with pip
- tried to install in a different new env with conda
- all of the above with a fresh anaconda install on windows 10

With matplotlib version 3.3.1 and Python version 3.6.11

Advice or thoughts on solution would be very appreciated.

Full error message below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-939c03ac8ea0> in <module>
      3 
      4 # import matplotlib
----> 5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

~\.conda\envs\SB36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>
     41 from matplotlib import docstring
     42 from matplotlib.backend_bases import FigureCanvasBase, MouseButton
---> 43 from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
     44 from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
     45 from matplotlib import rcParams, rcParamsDefault, get_backend, rcParamsOrig

~\.conda\envs\SB36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in <module>
     16 
     17 import matplotlib as mpl
---> 18 from matplotlib import docstring, projections
     19 from matplotlib import __version__ as _mpl_version
     20 

~\.conda\envs\SB36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\projections\__init__.py in <module>
      2 from .geo import AitoffAxes, HammerAxes, LambertAxes, MollweideAxes
      3 from .polar import PolarAxes
----> 4 from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
      5 
      6 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .axes3d import Axes3D

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py in <module>
     22 import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
     23 import matplotlib.docstring as docstring
---> 24 import matplotlib.projections as proj
     25 import matplotlib.scale as mscale
     26 import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'projections'
```

Comment: Looks to me like it is loading matplotlib components from more than one location which possibly means you have mismatched versions.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
How do I align my versions?

That is what I have read elsewhere. Clean install was the advice. Which is where I started with Matplotlib and did a full anaconda resinstall.
And left MPL as the last package install before testing it after a clean install of Anaconda (where I manually deleted pkg and env folders as per reinstall instructions) and in an new environment.

And just now removed via conda matplotlib and installed a fresh version.
(ran pip uninstall as well yet it found nothing )

Still same error.

Comment: Have you checked your PATH to see if it is still looking for modules in other paths containing python packages?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up.
Using an environment with python 3.7 seems to have fixed it.
Well not fixed the environment with python 3.6 yet it allowed me to have a working environment.

And yes, I checked what windows PATHs were setup. Things were as they should be (as evident by the fact the python 3.7 env worked).

Answer (score 0):

You probably have mismatched binaries.

Try:

```
conda uninstall matplotlib
```

Then:

```
conda install matplotlib
```

You can also try

```
conda update --all
```

Comment: I worked around the issue by making a new environment with Python 3.7

I had run conda remove/pip uninstall matplotlib, conda update --all, and install matplotlib.
Seems that is how others with similar issues got it to work,yet it didn't do the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

The work around that got a functioning environment was to create an environment with Python 3.7.